# Dynamic JSON unmarshalling from http response

Tags: arrays, go, pointers, interface, unmarshalling

I am writing a cli that will allow users to consume an API, which is pretty consistent in the requests and responses, but can grow over time and have quite complex jsons to deal with. So I am trying to build an easily extensible http client and methods for operating with different parts of the API. So far I have the following:

```golang
type (
    Doer interface {
        Do(req *http.Request) (*http.Response, error)
    }

    DoerFunc func(req *http.Request) (resp *http.Response, err error)

    Client struct {
        doer      Doer
        BaseURL   *url.URL
        UserAgent string
    }

    Services struct {
        Id   *int64  `json:"id,omitempty"`
        Name *string `json:"name,omitempty"`
        Team *string `json:"team,omitempty"`
    }
    request struct {
        Data interface{}
    }
)

func (c *Client) ListServices(ctx context.Context) ([]Services, error) {
    services := new([]Services)
    err := c.Request(ctx, "services", services)
    return *services, err
}

func NewClient(doer Doer) *Client {
    if doer == nil {
        doer = http.DefaultClient
    }
    baseURL, _ := url.Parse(defaultBaseURL)
    client := &Client{doer: doer, BaseURL: baseURL, UserAgent: conf.UserAgent + conf.GetVersion()}
    return client
}

func (c *Client) Request(ctx context.Context, path string, v interface{}) error {
    return c.request(ctx, "GET", path, nil, v)
}

// The response is populated into v
func (c *Client) request(ctx context.Context, method string, path string, data interface{}, v interface{}) error {
    rel, err := url.Parse(path)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    u := c.BaseURL.ResolveReference(rel)
    var body io.Reader
    //TODO
    if data != nil {
        b, err := json.Marshal(request{Data: data})
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        body = bytes.NewReader(b)
    }
    req, err := http.NewRequest(method, u.String(), body)
    req.Header.Set("Content-type", "application/json")
    req.Header.Set("User-Agent", "cli/"+conf.GetVersion())
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    resp, err := c.doer.Do(req.WithContext(ctx))
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer resp.Body.Close()
    res, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    err = json.Unmarshal(res, &v)
    return err
}
```

and then call to list services

```golang
    ctx := context.Background()

    ts := oauth2.StaticTokenSource(&oauth2.Token{AccessToken: token.AccessToken})
    tc := oauth2.NewClient(ctx, ts)

    client := NewClient(tc)

    services, err := client.ListServices(ctx)
    for _, service := range services {
        fmt.Println("Service:", services)
    }
```

But I receive:

> Service: {0xc0001ba750 0xc000142ac0  }

Can someone help me understand what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Given that you fmt.Println services which is a struct with pointer fields the expected output looks pretty sensible to me. What would you have expected?

Comment: What is your question? Why do you think you're doing something wrong?

Comment: Thanks, had the struct autogenerated, didnt pay attention to the pointers there. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Change your println to be:

```golang
    for _, service := range services {
        fmt.Printf("Service: %v\n", service)
    }
```

You will get more sensible output. I think you are overusing pointers as well, but I think the println will show things are working as expected.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to answer! I believe too that I am doing something wrong with the pointers, because even with the Printf I get:  Service: {0xc00009c160 0xc00047ca90 <nil> }

Comment: I just saw what was doing wrong. I got the struct autogenerated and had a pointer there. Once removed I got the desired output: Service: {A-team 1607317846068 johndoe}. Thanks again!

Comment: Glad you got it working